# When i use this php the results show all the table not the specific condition that table1.id = table2.id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

- table 1

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|   User_id Primary   |      Email       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         1           |      a@a.com     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         2           |      b@b.com     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

- table 2

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|   Post_id Primary   |  User_id Foreign |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         1           |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Here's the code

```
$conn1 = @mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','signup');

$sql1 = "SELECT post_pic ,post_text FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1
    ON (table2.User_id = table1.User_id) " ;

$result = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql1);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

so when im logged in user id=2 user id=1 posts are shown

Comment: Well, a join works exactly like a join would - but without seeing the data you're trying to associate, its hard for us to tell you why its not giving the result you're expecting.

Comment: If you want to limit selection of records to those belonging to a specific user id - then your statement should have an according WHERE clause …

Comment: qirel i edited it ... i tried where but still the problem isnt solved

Comment: So `id` in `table_2` is the user ID from `table1`? I hope your actual tables are named better.

Comment: As per your edit, your fields are named `User_id` and `User_id` - not `id` and `id`. You need to join on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the user id in your query, why you are getting images for user 1 is that your code at the moment runs as expected.

If you want to get data only for user1, you need to add a where clause specifying the user ID.

Like so:

```
//For Arguments Sake
$user_id = $_SESSION['loggedin_user_id'];

$sql1 = "SELECT post_pic ,post_text
         FROM table2
         INNER JOIN table1
         ON (table2.id = table1.id)
         WHERE table2.User_id = '$user_id'";
```

EDIT: Actually I just noticed that @04FS already mentioned it in a comment.

Comment: yes i forgot $user_id = $_SESSION['loggedin_user_id']; and i added the WHERE table.user id='$user_id'

Comment: If this answer worrked for you, accept it, because some other people could have the same problem as you!